# How to assign a global variable in multi-threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, global-variables, global

I am using multithreading and its working fine.In the first thread as mentioned in the code, I need my csv file to be saved with filename as Logger1 for the first time and after this logger1 file has crossed 1000 lines it should be converted into zip file, and removed while 'i' gets incremented by 1.Now after this, the further data should be saved in the csv file with filename as logger2.

If variable 'i' is assigned value the way, as shown in the code then unbound local error appears stating variable i is referenced before assignment. If I declare it like global i  instead of just i=1 in the beginning, same error appears. If I assigned value inside the u1thread this value never gets actually incremented because every time the thread is executed i is set to be 1.

```
    i=1
       class u1Thread(threading.Thread):
         def run(self):                              
           while True:                 
                 export_csv = x.to_csv (r'/home/pi/Logger' + str(i) 
                              + '.csv', index = None, mode='a', 
                             header=False)
                input_file = open("Logger" + str(i) + ".csv","r+")
                             reader_file = csv.reader(input_file)
                l = len(list(reader_file))
                if (l > 1000) :
                  jungle_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('Logger' + str(i) + 
                               '.zip', 'w')
                  jungle_zip.write('Logger' + str(i) + '.csv', 
                               compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
                  jungle_zip.close()
                  os.remove("Logger" + str(i) + ".csv")
                  i +=1

       class vfThread(threading.Thread):
         def run(self):
          while True:
          ret, frame=video.read()
```

Comment: To change the value of a global variable inside a function or method, it must be declared `global` _inside_ each one, preferably at the beginning of the `def`. To prevent problems with concurrent access to the variable, you should also create `Lock` variable and acquire the lock before referring to it's current value or changing it.

Comment: Please consider writing some python commands for it. I found that lock is useful when a variable is accessed by two or multiple threads.Here variable 'i' is just  needed for the first thread.

Comment: You can acquire a `Lock` variable after one is created by using a `with` context manager: i.e. `with mylock:` followed by an (indented) list of one or more statements that reference the protected global resource. This is because `Lock`s support the content management protocol, as mentioned in the online [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects).